# Dato tipo date se muestra con hora 12:00:00 am

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día.

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo una tabla Productos en SQL Server que tiene una columna donde se almacena la fecha de caducidad del producto, este dato se almacena con el tipo date. Pero a la hora de mostrarlo en mi interfaz desde C# en un DataGridView el dato se muestra con hora, por ejemplo, en si el producto caduca el día 10/05/2022, al hacer un SELECT en SQL Server solo se muestra la fecha, es decir, 10/05/2022, pero en el DataGridView se muestra como 10/05/2022 12:00:00 a.m. Y requiero que solo se muestre la fecha, es decir, sin la hora. ¿Cómo podría evitar esa hora?

Así creo la tabla en SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS(
    idproducto int identity primary key,
    fechacaducidad date
)
GO
```

Así hago la conexión con SQL desde C#:

```
List<Productos> lista = new List<Productos>();
{
using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.cadena))
            {
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                    query.AppendLine("SELECT idproducto,fechacaducidad FROM PRODUCTOS");

          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), oconexion);
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

          oconexion.Open();
           using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 while (dr.Read())
                 {
                    lista.Add(new Productos()
                 {
                 idproducto = Convert.ToInt32(dr["idproducto"]),
                 fechacaducidad = dr["fechacaducidad"].ToString()
             });
           }
         }
      }
      catch
      {
         lista = new List<Productos>();
      }
    }
  return lista;
}
```

En una clase aparte están las propiedades correspondiente a la tabla:

```
public class Productos
    {
        public int idproducto { get; set; }
        public string fechacaducidad { get; set; }
    }
```

Y así lo muestro en mi DGV (Esta parte esta dentro del evento Load de mi formulario):

```
List<Productos> listaproductos = new CN_Productos().Listar(); /*CN_Productos es otra clase donde se almacenan las validaciones, en este caso sirve como conexión entre la clase donde se encuentra la conexión a SQL y la clase donde se encuentran las propiedades.*/

            foreach (Productos item in listaproductos)
            {
                dgvMostrarDatos.Rows.Add(new object[] {"",
                    item.idproducto,
                    item.fechacaducidad
                });
            }
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

P.d. Haciendo un recorrido con puntos de depuración me di cuenta que el dato viene así desde la base de datos.

P.d.2 Disculpen por el desorden de los corchetes xd

Comment: esto de aqui te podra servir https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**En la sección donde le asignas valores a tu objeto, puedes especificarle el el formato de la fecha, como muestras un `string`, es mucho mejor para manejar**.

Tendrías algo como esto:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
     while (dr.Read())
     {
        lista.Add(new Productos()
     {
     idproducto = Convert.ToInt32(dr["idproducto"]),
     fechacaducidad = dr["fechacaducidad"].ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") //En esta parte especificas el formato.
 });
}
```

**Nota:** En caso de no funcionar, primero guarda tu valor en una variable `Datetime` y después le das formato.
Algo como:

```
//Ejemplo de obtener el valor de la fecha
//En su caso seria (var date = dr["fechacaducidad"])
var date = DateTime.Now;

string fechacaducidad = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Si ocurre un error entonces el valor que estas obteniendo es incorrecto con respecto al formato de fecha.

```
string fechacaducidad = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fechacaducidad"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Intente de ambas maneras y me arroja el siguiente error: Ninguna sobrecarga para el metodo 'ToString' toma 1 argumentos.

Comment: @ElWuichoNando10 eso es porque estas obteniendo mal tu valor de fecha. 
Revisa el código que voy a actualizarlo.

Comment: Al parecer ya hice que funcionara pero ahora no me lista ningún registro, supongo que se debe a un error en la conexión a SQL, lo hice de la siguiente manera:                         DateTime fechac = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fechacaducidad"]);
Y dentro del lista.add coloque: fechacaducidad = fechac.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: Lo estaba colocando mal xd, debía ir dentro del recorrido del While. Agradezco mucho tu ayuda y tu atención.